# Set Coordinate Reference System for a TIFF file

Tags: coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff

[image]I have a number of TIFF files which has been georeferenced using the QGIS georeferencer tool.  When I add them to my project they display in the correct location.  However, before the georeferencing tool was run the coordinate reference system for the new TIFF was not set so I get a warning that "Layer has no coordinate reference system set"  I can easily change the CRS for the layer and the warning disappears.  But how do set the CRS in the TIFF file?  I have tried using the Raster - Projections - Add projection.  When I run it the log says the algorithm is finished but nothing happens and the file is not updated.  Any suggestions how to fix it?

Comment: That answer deals with warping but in this case there is no need to warp, just to attach the CRS. One option is to use gdal_edit with -a_srs option.

Comment: Welcome to the community. You are right this often happens but actually, I never bothered before about it. Maybe steps explained [here](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/georeferencing_basics.html) can help.

Comment: @user30184 the QGIS tool uses the gdal_edit function but the TIFF file is not updated

Comment: Please show  the generated command and gdalinfo before and after. Have you tried to run the command from command line? Have you tried to use a file path that does not have spaces?

Comment: @user30184  the command is shown in the image above.  Not familiar with how to run it from the command line.  How would that be different from running it in QGIS?

Comment: I would try two things. 1. triple-check that the raster AND its folder have write permissions/are editable. 2. If the tool allows (looks like it doesn't), write the results to a new file.